# how to update oracle clob column ruby on rails, error: string literal too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, oracle12c, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to update an oracle clob column as follows:

```
MyData.where('id=?', id).update_all(['json=?', (json)])
```

I get the followning error:

> OCIError: ORA-01704: string literal too long: UPDATE "MYDATA"

I tried the following:

MyData.where('id=?', id).update_all(['json=?', to_clob(json)])

> undefined method `to_clob' for Class

How do i tell rails to use column as clob.

I am using oracle 12c, rails 5.1 and ruby-2.4.1

EDIT: update_all(json: json) clears the data for that column and makes it empty.

Comment: The problem is that your `update_all` is trying to send SQL like `update ... set json='some string longer than 4000 characters...' where id = ...` to the database and Oracle doesn't like string literals longer than 4k characters. AFAIK the proper solution is to use bound parameters but `update_all` might not be smart enough for that. Does `update_all(json: json)` behave better?

Comment: update_all(json: json) clears the data for that column and makes it empty.

Comment: Then you have to find a way to make the Oracle driver use a prepared statement with a bound parameter for the UPDATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I am using the following solution to make it work.

```
MyData.update(id, json: json)
```